# Default value for ##UserId## no longer works

Tags: bug, data-explorer

Normally, when I openend a [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/49864/my-comments-ordered-by-score-pundit-badge-progress) while logged in, `UserId` was pre-filled with my User ID on that particular site. This worked for all queries that used `##UserId##`.

**Now, it doesn't work.**

I am logged in, but I still have to fill in the UserId manually.

Comment: It's not for beta sites - this doesn't work for StackOverflow!

Comment: I clarified the original bug report.